# Необходимо ли использовать super?

Tags: python, ооп, наследование

Объясните, пожалуйста, чем этот код

```
class ClassName(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        super(ClassName, self).__init__()
        self.arg = arg
```

по сути отличается от этого

```
class ClassName(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        object.__init__(self)
        self.arg = arg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be usefull: [Understanding Python `super()` and `__init__()` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods)

Answer (score 6):

Различие этих двух блоков кода проявится тогда, когда они будут использоваться в цепочке наследований, например,

```
class A1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('a1')
        super(A1, self).__init__()


class A2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('a2')
        object.__init__(self)


class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('b')
        super(B, self).__init__()


class C1(A1, B):
    def __init__(self):
        print('c1')
        super(C1, self).__init__()


class C2(A2, B):
    def __init__(self):
        print('c2')
        super(C2, self).__init__()


C1()
print('-'*10)
C2()
```

В итоге будет следующий вывод:

```
c1
a1
b
----------
c2
a2
```

Как можно заметить, в первом случае наследование разрешилось правильно, а в случае использования прямого вызова `object.__init__(self)` мы лишили себя возможности использования нашего класса (`A2`) в сложных цепочках наследования, так как класс `B` в нашем примере не был проинициализирован.

Так что польза не столько в том, чтобы не изменять содержимое методов при изменении родительского класса, сколько в возможности корректного использования класса в наследовании.

Answer (score 4):

`super()` позволяет не писать класс-родитель. Он определяется динамически. PROFIT в том, что потом код будет легче менять - в случае изменения класса-родителя придется менять его в одном месте.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько понимаю, в данном отрывке кода только формальное - super все равно разрешится в тот же object. Однако конструкция с super все равно предпочтительней, потому что в этом случае класс-прослойка между object и ClassName будет легче добавляться.

Ну и если память не изменяет, то super в 2.7 работает только в отнаследованных от object объектах, поэтому в коде можно будет встретить обе конструкции.